# Gap groups commands

Tags: gap

I'm always needing to learn more about [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org).
Can anyone help me on the following question?
Question:
I have a list of 500 sublists where each sublist consists of six groups.
Is there a command to display or renumber only those sublists with trivial intersection?
Is there a function in GAP can solve this?

This questioning arose when I studied a problem on coverage of finite groups.

Comment: Just how is this set-theory related?

Comment: This is off-topic here, I think. Why not ask it in the GAP forum instead? http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html

Comment: coreFreeList := Filtered( list, sublist -> IsTrivial( Intersection( sublist ) ) );;

Comment: Thanks Jack Schmidt! This command solved the problem! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

This question is in fact answered in the comment by Jack Schmidt (thanks!):

```
coreFreeList := Filtered( list, sublist -> IsTrivial( Intersection( sublist ) ) );;
```

so I'm just answering it formally to prevent it from appearing in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: $\LARGE{+1}$ for my GAPy friend. :-)